# How to make multiple file uploading via CarrierWave and Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave

I'm not first who is asking and maybe not last. How to implement multiple uploading with CarrierWave in Sinatra? I'm using this code in action:

```
post '/create' do
  params.delete 'submit'
  d = Dcmnt.new(
    :published   => params[:published],
    :name        => params[:name],
    :description => params[:description],
    :created_at  => Time.now
  )
  d.attachment = params[:attachments]
  d.save
  redirect '/success'
end
```

With this model:

```
class Dcmnt
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'dcmnts'
  field :published,   type: Boolean
  field :name,        type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :created_at,  type: Date
  mount_uploader :attachment, Uploader, type: String
end
```

And this form:

```
%form{:method => "post", :action => "/create", :enctype => "multipart/form-data"}
  %input{:type => "checkbox", :name => "published", :value => "true"} Published?
  %input{:name => "name"}
  %textarea{:name => "description", :rows => "5"}
  %div.form-group
    %label Attachments
    %input{:type => "file", :name => "attachments[]"}
    %input{:type => "file", :name => "attachments[]"}
    %input{:type => "file", :name => "attachments[]"}
    %input{:type => "file", :name => "attachments[]"}
    %input{:type => "file", :name => "attachments[]"}
```

Also CW's configuration:

```
class Uploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    'attachments/' + model.id
  end
end
```

Looks correct, but doesn't work. When I'm trying to upload couple of files either single file, Pow returns me **no implicit conversion of nil into String** on **d.attachment = params[:attachments]** line. And I can't figure out why. Can you help me with this?

Comment: If I'm not getting wrong you have one database column `attachment` (which is mounted on carrierwave) and you want multiple entries to be save in database on that one column can you explain how that is logically possible unless I'm missing something

Comment: No, I'm just mounting uploader to Dcmnt class, attachments stores in */public/attachemnts/OBJ_ID* folder.

Comment: that right but `d.attachment = params[:attachments]`  I believe params would be array as oppose of file objects(`multipart`) as oppose to only file object(`multipart`)

Comment: If it more then one image (where each image in collection in mongodb) shouldnt it a separate class all together only specifically for it  like `class Attachment ; include Mongoid::Document;  field :image,type: String mount_upoloader :image,Uploader...` and use `referencing` or `embedding` a documents feature in mongoid/mongodb